# How to use Fontawesome Elements that is in an array inside a component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, font-awesome

I am trying to understand the react framework and es6 as I am totally new to modern JS. I have been doing OOPs previously and trying to understand Modern JS. Here in this code, I have a functional component inside a class component. I have used the Fontawesome library for react. The icons are kept inside an array named information. When I render this Class component, the font-awesome icon won't render though the name part of the array is showing

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faDesktop, faServer, faMobile} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const information = [
    {"fontName" : "faDesktop", "name" : "Website"},
    {"fontName" : "faServer","name" : "Web App"},
    {"fontName" : "faMobile","name" : "Mobile App"},

]
const Service=(props)=>{
    return (
        <>
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon={props.fontName} size="6x"/>
    <h6>{props.name }</h6>
    </>
    );
}
export default class Services extends Component {



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <h2>Our Services</h2>

                           {information.map((info )=> 
                            <div className="col s12 m4 l4">
                            <Service icon={info.fontName} name={info.name}/>
                            </div>
                           )}



                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }


}
```

My Queries -
1. How to use Fontawesome icons in an array and pass as props to the Service Component.
2. When to use class-based component or functional component. Can we mix up both the same?
3. When to use es6 features and normal js? 
it's confusing, some resources will be helpful from JS masters.

Answer (score 0):

If its mandatory to pass the icon name as string to `service` component then you can create an object of fontawesome icons which you are trying to import in file.
`fontName` is being passed to `Service` Component is of string type, however the forawesome variables `faDasktop` and other icons do not have the value of string type

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faDesktop, faServer, faMobile} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const mapIcons = {
   faDesktop, faServer, faMobile
}


const information = [
    {"fontName" : "faDesktop", "name" : "Website"},
    {"fontName" : "faServer","name" : "Web App"},
    {"fontName" : "faMobile","name" : "Mobile App"},

]
const Service=(props)=>{
    return (
        <>
    {mapIcons[props.fontName] && (
      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={mapIcons[props.icon]} size="6x"/>
    )}
    <h6>{props.name }</h6>
    </>
    );
}
export default class Services extends Component {



    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <h2>Our Services</h2>

                           {information.map((info )=> 
                            <div className="col s12 m4 l4">
                            <Service icon={info.fontName} name={info.name}/>
                            </div>
                           )}



                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }


}
```

Comment: it didn't work even passing the values as objects of icons rather than strings.

Comment: Context of the icon object iis not reachable inside the component I think.